# Using either Quit button or received serial commands to close Tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter, arduino

I tried to use either (1) Quit button or (2) received serial commands (through the remote controller via Arduino) to close Tkinter window with the below Python script. I expected that if '0' is pressed via remote controller, my Tk window should be closed

```
# the 1st code start
from tkinter import *
import serial
import time

window = Tk()
window.geometry("300x300")

def close_window():
    window.destroy()

button = Button(text="Quit",font=("Arial",10), command=close_window)
button.pack()

ser = serial.Serial("COM5", 115200)

window.mainloop()

while True:
    var2 = ser.readline()

    # press the remote control 0, then break
    if var2 == b'0\r\n': 
        close_window()
        print('Exit the code')
        break

    # press the remote control 1, then continue (just for testing purposes)
    elif var2 == b'1\r\n':
        print('Continue the code')
        pass 

    time.sleep(0.01)
```

Here, (1) Quit button worked, but (2) pressing 0 didn't work and I got the below error.
can't invoke "destroy" command.

Without using `Tkinter`, the following remote controller script worked, which is about terminating the script by pressing 0 through the remote controller.

```
# the 2nd code start
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial("COM5", 115200)

while True:
    var2 = ser.readline()

    # press the remote control 0, then break
    if var2 == b'0\r\n': 
        print('Exit the code')
        break

    # press the remote control 1, then continue (just for testing purposes)
    elif var2 == b'1\r\n':
        print('Continue the code')
        pass

    time.sleep(0.01)
```

Comment: FWIW, any code after the call to `mainloop` won't run until after the window has been destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

Once your code gets to mainloop() it stops there and just loops over and over the gui code.

You can alternatively update root yourself and intersperse your own code.  For instance (untested):

```
shouldExit = False

while not shouldExit:
   window.update()
   window.update_idletasks()
   var = ser.readline()
   if var == b'0\r\n':
      shouldExit = True
   time.sleep(0.01)
```

And then destroy your root window after the while loop or just let the program there.

EDIT:

Here's the code with both methods.  shouldExit has to be global.

```
from tkinter import *
import serial
import time

window = Tk()
window.geometry("300x300")

shouldExit = False

def close_window():
    global shouldExit
    shouldExit = True

button = Button(text="Quit",font=("Arial",10), command=close_window)
button.pack()

#ser = serial.Serial("COM5", 115200)


while not shouldExit:
    window.update()
    window.update_idletasks()
    var = ser.readline()

    # press the remote control 0, then break
    if var == b'0\r\n': 
        print('Exit the code')
        shouldExit = True

    # press the remote control 1, then continue (just for testing purposes)
    elif var == b'1\r\n':
        print('Continue the code')
        pass

    time.sleep(0.01)

quit()
```

Comment: Can I further use the same stopflag (shouldExit) to be binded with the button? Please see what tried below.